Display coupons codes and discount amounts used on an order in WooCommerce
I am trying to display the amount of the coupon used on an order with the following:
foreach( $order->get_coupons() as $item ){
    $code   = $item->get_code();
    $coupon = new WC_Coupon($code);

    $html .= '<tr>
        <td>' . ucfirst( $code ) . '</td>
        <td>' . $coupon->get_amount() . '</td>
    </tr>';
}

But instead, it is displaying the balance left of each coupon code used.
How can I display the coupons discount amounts used on an order in WooCommerce?
